# setting Paper to PageFormatter does not update the PageFormatter

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am trying to print my Jpanel. I works for most part. Now i am trying to customize some things like the margin.

Here is my code

```
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

//*
PageFormat pf0 = pjob.defaultPage();
Paper p = pf0.getPaper();

//hardcode the page imageable area for testing. The sizes are valid ones i pulled from calling printerJob.getDialog(attr)...)
p.setImageableArea(28, 28, 556, 734);
pf0.setPaper(p);

//set the attributes for the formatter
PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr_set.add(Fidelity.FIDELITY_TRUE);
attr_set.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);
attr_set.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);
attr_set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

//set the printable area
int width = Math.round(MediaSize.NA.LETTER.getX(MediaSize.MM));
int height = Math.round(MediaSize.NA.LETTER.getY(MediaSize.MM));
attr_set.add(new MediaPrintableArea(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20, MediaPrintableArea.MM));

//update the page formatter
pf0 = pjob.getPageFormat(attr_set);
```

Even though i am calling `pf0.setPaper(p)` the paper object in `pf0` (the page formatter) does not update. Here is the screen from my debugger that shows that the value has not changed.

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Several things, first, you are setting the imageable twice. First via the `Paper` and second via the `MediaPrintableArea`.  The `PrintJob` will make alterations to the `PageFormat` based on a number of factors, including the capabailities of the printer...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've played around with this.  So using your example I get...

```
// Paper.setImageableArea
28 pixels = 0.99 cm (x)
28 pixels = 0.99 cm (y)
556 pixels = 19.653 cm (width)
734 pixels = 25.945 cm (height)

// PrintRequestAttributeSet
29.528 pixels = 1 cm (x)
29.528 pixels = 1 cm (y)
578.74 pixels = 19.6 cm (width)
764.764 pixels = 25.9 cm (height)

// Page format AFTER getting it from the PrintJob
72 pixels = 2.545 cm (x)
72 pixels = 2.545 cm (y)
697.918 pixels = 24.669 cm (width)
451.332 pixels = 15.953 cm (height)
```

Which, obviously isn't what your expecting.

Next, I added `attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);` to the `PrintRequestAttributeSet`

```
// Page format AFTER getting it from the PrintJob
22.082 pixels = 0.781 cm (x)
72 pixels = 2.545 cm (y)
697.918 pixels = 24.669 cm (width)
451.332 pixels = 15.953 cm (height)
```

Which still isn't what you're expecting...

Now if I use `pf0 = pjob.pageDialog(attr_set);` instead of `pf0 = pjob.getPageFormat(attr_set);`

```
// Page format AFTER getting it from the PrintJob
30 pixels = 1.06 cm (x)
28 pixels = 0.99 cm (y)
734 pixels = 25.945 cm (width)
556 pixels = 19.653 cm (height)
```

Which is pretty much what you set to begin with (note, the width and height have been swapped because the page is in landscape)...

So...bug...and welcome to the wonderful world of WHY??!?!

After some digging, I found that the `MediaPrintableArea` is been ignored and some circumstances because of a call to `service.isAttributeValueSupported(orientReq, null, attributes)` where `service` is the `PrintService`.  This could have to do with the default printer...??